# When searching and printing strings from a file, every line prints instead of the one I need

Tags: c, macos, scanf, strcmp

I am attempting to create a program that allows me to search for a name in a text file. At this point the program will successfully tell me whether or not the name is on the roster, but it will also print every other line as well! For example, if I am looking to see if "Sarah" will be on the roster, it will say

```
Sarah is not on the roster
Sarah is number 7 on the roster
Sarah is not on the roster
```

I simply want it to tell me if "Sarah" is on the roster or not. I'm very, very new to teaching myself C, so I'm assuming I'm doing something stupid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *inFile;
    inFile = fopen("workroster.txt", "r");
    char rank[4], gname[20], bname[20];
    char name[20];

    printf("Enter a name: __");
    scanf("%s", name);
    while(fscanf(inFile, "%s %s %s", rank, bname, gname)!= EOF)          
    {
        if(strcmp(gname,name) == 0)
            printf("%s is number %s on the roster\n", name, rank);
        else
            printf("%s is not on the roster\n", name);
    }
    fclose(inFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because you look at each item (or each line) and say something. Your text should be "Item #1 isn't Sarah", "Item #2 isn't Sarah", "Item #3 is Sarah" and so on. Keep the information in a variable and move the print statement out of the loop, so that is just executes once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of whether the `name` was *found*, and only print the *"not on the roster"* message if you finish the `while` loop without finding the name.

```
int found = 0;
while(fscanf(inFile, "%s %s %s", rank, bname, gname)== 3)          
{
    if(strcmp(gname,name) == 0)
    {
        printf("%s is number %s on the roster\n", name, rank);
        found = 1;
    }
}

if ( !found )
    printf("%s is not on the roster\n", name);
```

Comment: That `!= EOF` test should be `== 3`.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the `EOF`. Note sure I agree with the `strstr`, since for example, `ali` would match `alice`

Comment: Nor do I now.  I removed that from my comment.

Comment: Unless there's a desire to know that Sarah is on the roster multiple times (or multiple people called Sarah are on the roster with different numbers), you could use `break;` after `found = 1;` to stop the loop early.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler In the original, I had the `break`, but then it occurred to me that there *could* be multiple players with the same name.

Comment: ... so you probably want to know how many times she was found, otherwise `break;` still stands.

Comment: There are pros (speed, mainly) and cons (lack of thoroughness) to breaking early.  Both designs are justifiable. At this stage, going through and counting how many Sarah's there are might be best (so the `found++` that @trojanfoe suggested — and report if `found == 0` and a separate report if `found > 1`).  If there are millions of records and the 'names' are pretty much guaranteed to be unique, the `break` solution might save quite a lot of time — but maybe you'd be using a different data structure by the time the files got that big.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you all very much. I knew it had to be something braindead on my part. Why is the !=EOF not usable or not recommended?

Comment: @eruiggy You're welcome, glad to help. It's always a good idea to verify that the return value from `fscanf` is equal to the number of requested conversions. If the return is any other value, then something went wrong. Using your code as an example, if `fscanf` returns 2, then that means that nothing was put into `gname`, so then the `strcmp` is invalid (and may cause the program to crash). To be really safe, you should read a line from the file with `fgets`, then parse the line with `sscanf`, and verify that `sscanf` returns 3. That way, you know immediately if the input line is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a `flag` and check if the name exists or not.